# Problems with centering divs

Tags: html, css

I have two divs in my page end I want to center the second one between the first and the end ofthe page. Something like this:

```
|   |          | |    | | 
|   |          | |    | |
|   |   div1   | |div2| |
|   |          | |    | |
|   |          | |    | |
```

"Div 2" is supposed to be centered between "div 1" and the end of the page. I tried everything I know and nothing worked.

My HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="teste.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="teste.js"></script>

    <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="header">
        <div class="title"">Example</div>
    </div>

    <div id="main-body">
        <ul class="nav-tabs">
            <li class="active-tab"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="right-menu"></div>

    <footer>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
/* Fonte Nunito a ser usada no título */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito);

/*----------------------------------------------*/

/* Cor do fundo da página */
body {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

/*----------------------------------------------*/

/* Header */

/* Cor e tamanho */
#header {
    background-color: #669966;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

/* Título */
#header .title {
    color: #cccccc;
    font-family: Nunito;
    font-size: 50px;
        font-style: italic;
        line-height: 46px;
    left: 60px;
        top: 30px;
    position: absolute;
}

/*----------------------------------------------*/

/* Tabs */
.nav-tabs {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

/* Tab cells */
.nav-tabs li {
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 10px 90px 10px 90px;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;

}

/* Tab ativa */
.active-tab {
    background-color: white;
    color: red;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 10px 90px 10px 90px;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}

a:link {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*----------------------------------------------*/

/* Main body (this is "div 1")*/

#main-body {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}

/*----------------------------------------------*/

/* Menu à direita(this is "div 2") */

#right-menu {
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}

/*----------------------------------------------*/

/* Footah */

footer {
    background-color: #333333;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Can someone help please?

**[EDIT]**
Thank you everyone who posted your solutions. The problem was solved!

Comment: there are 3 div in your code and shown structure and demo structure is totally different..please edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting close.

You need to make two outer divs that will, together, hold the full width of the page (one for the main column at say 70% wide, and one for the right column at 30% wide). Then inside your right column, place another div with fixed width and use text-align: center on the outer div.

Answer (score 0):

First put `#right-menu` **before** `#main-body`:

```
<div id="right-menu"></div>

<div id="main-body">
        <ul class="nav-tabs">
```

The set/modify these CSS rules

```
#main-body {
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
}

#right-menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: calc(((100% - 900px) / 4) - 25px);
}
```

The `right:` calculation works like this: From the full page width (100%) we remove the main width (900px); this give us the remaining width for both sides (left and right) so we divide it by two to have the width of one side then divide it by two again to have half of the size of one side. This will give us the exact position center of the free space on the left or the right (you can change the `right:` property to `left:` so you'll center it on left. Finally to center the element itself we subtract half of the right menu width (50px / 2 = 25px).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9jrLat77/

CSS should be something like this

```
/* Fonte Nunito a ser usada no título */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito);

/*----------------------------------------------*/

/* Cor do fundo da página */
body {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

/*----------------------------------------------*/

/* Header */

/* Cor e tamanho */
#header {
    background-color: #669966;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

/* Título */
#header .title {
    color: #cccccc;
    font-family: Nunito;
    font-size: 50px;
        font-style: italic;
        line-height: 46px;
    left: 60px;
        top: 30px;
    position: absolute;
}

/*----------------------------------------------*/

/* Tabs */
.nav-tabs {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

/* Tab cells */
.nav-tabs li {
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 10px 90px 10px 90px;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;

}

/* Tab ativa */
.active-tab {
    background-color: white;
    color: red;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 10px 90px 10px 90px;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}

a:link {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*----------------------------------------------*/

/* Main body (this is "div 1")*/

#main-body {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}

/*----------------------------------------------*/

/* Menu à direita(this is "div 2") */

#right-menu {
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    width: calc(100% - 920px);
    display: block;
    float:right;
}


.content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try working with bootstrap. Its a framework that makes it alot easier to format your page. you can set it up by including these lines in your code:

Bootstraps "container" has a width of 12. So if you set up the first div with a width of 5 and your second div width of 3 then you could set it up like this:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="row">
<div id="col-md-5">div 1 </div>
<div id="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2"> div 2 </div>
</div> </div>
```

the md part stands for medium and can be any size you want (xs, sm, md, lg)
the offset is due to the fact that you have 12 width so you have to move it over 2 to center it if the widths are 5 and 3.

Comment: I tried working with Bootstrap, but to be honest I didn't like it >.< It's hard to customize and sometimes messes up with the whole page...

Comment: Well for this particular situation it would be easy to format. You wouldnt have to us BS3 anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<style type="text/css">
 body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
 }

 #right {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  float: right;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 300px;
 }

 #main {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 900px;
 }
</style>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = setMargin;
 window.onresize = setMargin;

 function setMargin() {
  var x = window.innerWidth;
  var y = x - 900 - 300;
  var z = y / 2;

  document.getElementById("right").style.marginRight = z;
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest method here I feel is to have a wraooing div on the right hand side that takes up the remaining width...then center the menu block inside that.

I've used floats here (rather than inline-block) for simplicity as the white-space affect the `calc` values unless you reset them.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Main body (this is "div 1")*/

#main-body {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 900px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  float: left;
}
/*----------------------------------------------*/

/* Menu à direita(this is "div 2") */

#right-wrap {
  background: #bada55;
  width: calc(100% - 1005px);
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
#right-menu {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-body">
  <ul class="nav-tabs">
    <li class="active-tab"><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="right-wrap">
  <div id="right-menu"></div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/NqOVGN)

Comment: Thank you, this is the one that worked better :D But could you explain why you subtracted especifically 1005px from the full width?

Comment: Because you have an element that is 900px wide with a total of 105px margin on it...so 900 +105 = 1005. :)